# Mercurial: ignore files if the file with different extension is present

Tags: mercurial, org-mode

In my mercurial repository I have a lot of different files. For example .org and .tex files. Exporting the .org file generates a .tex file. Normally I do not want to ignore .tex files since these are usually source files. But I am looking for something like:

```
foo.org present => ignore foo.tex
foo.org absent => do not ignore foo.tex
```

Comment: You could also ignore the files manually, possibly with a helper script for noticing which files should be ignored. Too much of automating the work could lead data loss one day (e.g. because you happen to manually create a .tex file and do not notice that there is already a corresponding .org file. At least it already happened to me, but I noticed thanks to manual handling.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option available in Mercurial.

What you could do is [create an extension of your own](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WritingExtensions) to make some kind of 'hg customstatus' command available. This could be a wrapper around the 'hg status' command that executes the filtering you want.